# Why should SVG files have a space on Mac?

Tags: svg

In the [SVG Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html), the following is stated in Section 1.2

> It is recommended that SVG files stored on Macintosh HFS file systems be given a file type of "svg " (all lowercase, with a space character as the fourth letter). It is recommended that gzip-compressed SVG files stored on Macintosh HFS file systems be given a file type of "svgz" (all lowercase).

What does this mean, and is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the hfs file system the type of a file is not indicated by an extension but you set the file type as an metadata attribute, for example by calling the terminal program [`SetFile`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/SetFile.1.html). The file type must be a string consisting of 4 characters and that's the reason for the space as an fourth chatcter after `svg`.

See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_code  for further information.

Also note that your cited paragraph is removed in the upcoming [svg 2 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/intro.html#MIMEType).